# How do you add a service in Angular so a controller can use it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a basic angular setup. I want to add another factory service so that the mainCtrl can use it.

Here is my **controller.js**

```
angular.module('Manalator.controllers', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, manaFactory) {
        manaFactory.testString();
    }]);
```

Here is my **services.js**

```
angular.module('Manalator.services', [])
    .factory('cordovaReady', [function () {
        return function (fn) {
            var queue = [],
                impl = function () {
                    queue.push([].slice.call(arguments));
                };

            document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
                queue.forEach(function (args) {
                    fn.apply(this, args);
                });
                impl = fn;
            }, false);

            return function () {
                return impl.apply(this, arguments);
            };
        };
    }])
    .factory('manaFactory', [function(){
        this.testString = function(){
          return 'This works';
        };
    }]);
```

Here is my routes.js

```
angular.module('Manalator', ['ngRoute', 'Manalator.services', 'Manalator.controllers'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'MainCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'partials/pages/main.html'
            })
            .when('/devotion', {
                controller: 'MainCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'partials/pages/devotion.html'
            })
            .when('/results', {
                controller: 'MainCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'partials/pages/results.html'
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    });
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'testy' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (controllers.js:3)
    at Object.i [as invoke] (main.min.js:1)
    at $get.f.instance (main.min.js:2)
    at m (main.min.js:1)
    at s (main.min.js:1)
    at $get.e (main.min.js:1)
    at main.min.js:1
    at p.$get.p.$eval (main.min.js:3)
    at p.$get.p.$apply (main.min.js:3)
    at main.min.js:1
```

It is a cordova phonegap setup with basic routes. I am new to angular. I have looked over the internet and im having trouble setting up a basic service to hold all my data so i can access it from all my routes. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to identify your services as a dependency of the controller.

The first step is to make sure you define the services before the controller.

then change the controller code so that it names the services as a dependency.

```
angular.module('Manalator.controllers', ['Manalator.services'])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, manaFactory) {
    manaFactory.testString();
}]);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: pretty sure `manaFactory` needs to be declared as a dependency as well :)

Comment: Thanks! i have added it to the controller like this. but it still errors. do i not need to add it to the routes?